# Best way to receive data of unknown size?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm making an IRC bot in order to learn about sockets, but I'm having a little trouble.
I wrote a function that sends the commands required to initiate a connection to the IRC server as specified in [RFC1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459.html). And for receiving, I've here this function:

```
int receiveData(int socketDescriptor)
{
    char receiveBuffer[512];
    receiveBuffer[512] = '\0';
    recv(socketDescriptor, receiveBuffer, 511, 0);
    printf("%s\n", receiveBuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

(Whole program so far here: http://lpaste.net/103646)

As you may know, the first thing an IRC server dumps at you after that initial exchange is the MoTD, however, the message of the day is typically pretty lengthy and may also vary in that respect, so I think I may need to use a linked list of dynamic arrays to store it but I've never implemented anything like that before, so here's my question.

Do I need a linked list of dynamic arrays, and if yes then how do I implement it here?

Comment: Don't over complicate things for your self. A data structure (list or any thing else) is for representation or retrieval. Not for some physical needs of reading from the network. Just call read in a buffer (array) in a loop of say size 100 each time AND TEST the return value of recv which tells you how many bytes have actually been read. Then you can store the info into any structure convenient for your program needs. Also printf with %s would terminate printing   on the first space or new line. So it does not show the entire data present.

Comment: Section 2.3 Messages on page 8 of RFC1459 says: _IRC messages are always lines of characters terminated with a CR-LF (Carriage Return - Line Feed) pair, and these messages shall not exceed 512 characters in length, counting all characters including the trailing CR-LF. Thus, there are 510 characters maximum allowed for the command and its parameters._  You can, therefore, use a fixed-size buffer of up to 512 characters for reading the data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  the MOTD comes in multiple lines, I think the problem they want solve is to how to store the MOTD if its an arbitary size.  Which a linked list would be good for

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, the 510-character is the maximum for an IRC message, but that has no relation to how many characters might be read from the TCP-based socket.

Comment: IRC Messages are **always** lines of characters terminated with CRLF. That must include a multi-line MOTD unless you can point to another section of the RFC that says the MOTD is not an IRC Message. You're correct there might be more bytes in the socket, but any attempt to read 512 characters after the prefix should encounter CRLF; otherwise, the data stream is corrupt. And the MOTD might come as multiple lines; that's not a major problem. You could also prove me wrong by showing the trace from an IRC client with a long MOTD...but the spec says what it says and RFCs usually mean what they say.

Comment: `receiveBuffer[512] = '\0';` is a buffer overflow. For an array of size `512` the valid indices are `0` through `511`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forgive me for this slight diversion, but the way you've asked the question leads me to believe this is warranted.

Dealing with TCP-based protocols can be challenging at first because it is sometimes difficult to grasp that what you get from the socket has nothing to do with how the higher-level protocol is structured.  TCP is stream-based and is meant to ensure that the receiver gets the data that was sent by the sender *in the order it was originally transmitted*.  It makes absolutely no guarantees about how much data you will receive on any given read from the socket, much less how that maps into the higher-level messages.

For example, consider a sender that wishes to transmit two messages back-to-back over a TCP socket.  Say that message A is 200 bytes and message B is 500 bytes.  When you read from the socket, you might get 100 bytes, 200 bytes, 400 bytes, or 700 bytes (or any variation in between).  You simply have no way of knowing how much data will be retrieved on any given read of the socket.  Worse, you cannot count on each read from the socket returning a single. complete message.  You might get a partial message, a complete message, or multiple messages at once.

So how does one deal with this?  Well, a linked list could be made to work, but I think that makes things more complicated than they need to be.  For my purposes, I use two buffers - a receive buffer and a working buffer.  My receive buffer tends to be statically-sized and equal to the size of the socket's receive buffer (which I believe is 8KB on Windows by default...not sure what OS you're using).  Each and every read from the socket writes the data into the receive buffer starting at byte 0.  After this data has been read, I copy it from the receive buffer to the tail end of the working buffer, which for your purposes can be a large statically-sized array.  This allows me to piece the data stream back together into a consecutive array of data that is very easy to parse from.  I use index variables to keep track of where I am in the working buffer, e.g., `startPos`, `lastPos`, etc.

Returning to the example, let's say that the first read gets 250 bytes.  That's the full 200 bytes of message A and the first 50 bytes of message B.  I copy this to the tail end of the working buffer and update the index variables.  Of course, since we just started, this happens to be the beginning of the working buffer.  So now I examine the working buffer to see if I have a full message or not.  Well, message A is complete, but what type of message is it?  Examining the message indicates it's a `Foo` message.  I instantiate a `Foo` object and then fill the fields with the data from the message.  This `int` here, that `short` there, that `double` over there.  Once the `Foo` message has been processed, I return to the working buffer.  At this point, I no longer need the first 200 bytes, so I copy the last 50 bytes to the beginning of the working buffer and update the index variables.  So then I check to see if the 50 bytes represents a complete message, and of course at this point, the answer is no.

So back to the socket for more data.  The next read gives me another 250 bytes into the receive buffer.  I copy that to the tail end of the working buffer so that the working buffer now has a total of 300 bytes, and I update the index variables.  I check to see if the 300 bytes represents a complete message, and again, the answer is no.

Back to the socket again.  The next read gives me another 200 bytes into the receive buffer.  Another copy to the tail end of the working buffer and update to the index variables.  I now have 500 bytes in the working buffer.  I check to see if it is a complete message, and it is.  What kind of message?  It's a `Bar` message.  I instantiate a `Bar` object and then fill the fields with the data from the message.  At this point, the working buffer has been completely processed, so I simply update the index variables (since there's no shifting of data).

That's how I do it in a nutshell.  Read - copy - process - update - repeat.

Some of the gotchas to watch out for...

What I've described is a single-threaded approach to processing TCP-based data.  In practice, I use at least two threads for doing this, one to service the socket, and the other to process the data.  The danger of a single-threaded approach is that you spend so much time processing the data that you do not adequately service the socket.  I suspect that you do not have to worry about this for IRC, and I certainly understand that you're learning.  Just be aware that this would be a consideration going forward.

The other gotcha to be aware of is the size of the working buffer.  What you don't want to run into is a situation where you've read data from the socket into the receive buffer, but you don't have enough room in the working buffer to copy the data.  The way out of this hold is to use a statically-sized array for the receive buffer, but a dynamically-sized array for the working buffer that can grow to accommodate increasing traffic loads.  Again, for IRC, a large statically-sized working buffer (say, 8MB) would probably be overkill.  But moving the solution I've described to processing an XML-based stream or a very high traffic load would be insufficient.

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: I think I might save this to a text file for future reference.

Comment: I'm a little late here, but I'm wondering, why do you copy the data to the tail end of the working buffer instead of the beginning?

Comment: Because TCP is a stream of data.  The data you receive last goes *at the end* of any data remaining in the working buffer to be processed.